# Importing an irregular sized text file

Tags: python, pandas, import, text-files

I would like to import a text file that has 11576 rows and 7 columns into a pandas dataframe and then reshape it so that it has 229 rows and 351 columns.

In the text file, every 34 lines or so, there are 2 whitespaces (i.e the 6th and 7 th column of that row have no values).

I want to slice the data at this point and assign all the previous data as being in row one but, I do not know how to cut the data at that point and place it all in one row.

I have tried `pd.read_csv` but I can`t make it into the dimensions that I need.

Any suggestions would be really great.
Thanks
Emma

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6pmwxi2hznrrn57/AACdLW4VDH4HnLeq_HKIUVixa?dl=0) is a link to the text file.

Comment: Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Or better add file to question if data not confidental?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for create `DataFrame` and then [`numpy.reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) with select all columns without 2 last:

```
df = pd.read_csv('fieldgen_out1.txt', skiprows=1, header=None, sep='\s+')
#print (df)

#[351 rows x 229 columns]
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(351, -1)[:, :-2])
#print (df)
```

And then if necessary transpose:

```
#[229 rows x 351 columns]
df = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(351, -1)[:, :-2].T)
#print (df)
```